# How can I setup SCSS files (ViewEncapsulated way) in 'react app 2' like Angular component specific SCSS?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I installed 'react app 2' as well as node-sass. It's working fine with SCSS. But I just want to know how can I create component specific SCSS like Angular (that will never be a conflict with other components SCSS)

Angular automatically add an attribute for ViewEncapsulation see below example

[image]

[image]

[image]

In angular, there is an option for

encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None (Use to disable CSS Encapsulation for this component)
[enter link description here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-components)

Comment: Are you looking for an automated way to do this?

Comment: No, not really. If you can show me an automated way that would be appreciated. I just find a way automated or manually (anything)

Comment: This needs upvotes! Have you found ant work around yet @SubhajitPanja?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but it has no answer, thus I want to share [this article](https://dev.to/viclafouch/how-to-scope-your-css-scss-in-react-js-271a). Alsomst does the trick, with the exception that it seems to does not have support for something like ::ng-deep

Answer (score -2):

React doesn't have native component styles like Angular does because it aims to keep away from any functionality that could easily be handled by third-party packages. So you have two pretty simple options:

1. Use [`styled-components`](https://www.styled-components.com) to create component-specific styles. This is a pretty straightforward package that allows you to define styles for each element within a component and you can even pass variables into the styles. It generates internal CSS (kept in `<style>` tags in the document head) which will take precedence over external styles by default. Example:

   ```
   // MainComponent.jsx
   import React from 'react';
   import styled from 'styled-components';

   const Title = styled.h1`
     color: red
   `

   const MainComponent = (props) => <Title>Hello World</Title>
   ```
2. In each of your components, add a class or ID to the root element so that you can simply add that selector to the beginning of your SCSS to only style that specific component. Example:

   ```
   // MainComponent.jsx
   import React from 'react';

   const MainComponent = (props) => (
     <div className="main-component">
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
     </div>
   )

   // MainComponent.scss
   .main-component {
     h1 {
       color: red;
     }
   }
   ```

   Now only h1 elements in your MainComponent will be red.

Comment: "Now only h1 elements in your MainComponent will be red." Why won't the h1 elements of its children also be red?

Comment: @JohnK h1 elements anywhere inside the .main-component will be red.

Answer (score -4):

```js
//JS
import React from "react";
import "./yourComponentName.scss";

export default props => {
  const { className, children, ...restOperator } = props;
  
  return (
    <a className={`yourComponentName ${className}` } {...restOperator}>
      {children}
    </a>
  );
}
```

```css
//yourComponentName.scss

.yourComponentName{
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    /* your property and value use nesting*/

    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    li { display: inline-block; }
    
    a {
        display: block;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```